# html styling to css styling converter broke my background menu

Tags: html, css, styling

My old HTML styled page had a functioning background changer.As shown below.

```
<div style="position:fixed; z-index:999; top:11px; right:2px">
<form name="bgcolorForm"><font size="4" color="#FFFFFF">Background: </font>
<select onChange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0)
document.bgColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="choose"></option>
<option value="CBECE8">Standard</option>
<option value="FFFFCC">Cream</option>
<option value="FE2EF7">Pink</option>
<option value="CCFFCC">light green</option>
<option value="CCCCCC">gray</option>
<option value="FFFFFF">white</option>
<option value="00FFE2">Turqoise</option>
<option value="FF004D">Red</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

However after putting this code into an error checker at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org).
I was confronted with a ton of requests to add css instead of HTML styling.
So i asked for the fixed code and i used that in a seperate file.
But...The code for the menu no longer seems to work, I did make some small changes to the contents and positioning, But i didn't expect it to be 'broken'
This is what i was given:

```
....
<head>
....
div.c8 {position:fixed; z-index:999; top:55px; left:3px}
....

<div class="c8">
<form name="bgcolorForm" id="bgcolorForm"><select onchange="if(this.selectedIndex!=0)
document.bgColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option value="choose">Background</option>
<option value="CBECE8">Standard</option>
<option value="FFFFCC">Cream</option>
<option value="FE2EF7">Pink</option>
<option value="CCFFCC">Pale green</option>
<option value="CCCCCC">Gray</option>
<option value="FFFFFF">White</option>
<option value="00FFE2">Turqoise</option>
<option value="FF004D">Red</option>
</select></form>
</div>
```

I'm not quite sure whats broken, but i kinda need it fixed.
Huge thanks to anyone that can help!

Comment: What do you mean by "broken?" What isn't working? Is there a link to the page? You mention the menu at one point, but the question isn't clear.

Comment: "Background:" should be in a `<label>` with a `for` attr.

Comment: +Brian Bennett  By broken i mean, when i used the previous code, which was styled in html, the background menu worked, But now its styled in css it doesn't change the background anymore.

Comment: The original working page [here](http://michael-longhurst.xyz/error/SUC.html)
New 'broken' page [here](http://michael-longhurst.xyz/error/SUC-new.html)

Comment: @Brian Bennet   I'm sorry, i'm new to here, so i didn't realise you had to use '@' for the name. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS is overriding the `form` script running when users select the color. I'm guessing it was added when the code validator generated CSS based on the page code you submitted. Just remove the `background-color` property from the `body` tag in the CSS file (line 13 in the HTML) and the switcher works again. I'd set the default page color in your drop down with something like:

```
<form>
  <select>
    <option value="#FFF">Default</option>
    <!-- The rest go here... -->
  </select>
</form>
```

That way, the page will always load with the default option selected and you don't have to style it in the CSS.

Comment: Thank you hugely, this works now, But the page default colour is now white when it's loaded... It should be #CEBCE8.  thanks if you know how to do this!